# Scala: Problems use java interfaces

Tags: java, scala, interface

i wanted to use the `JemmyFX Framework`, which is written in `Java`, in Scala. But there are several problems that i cannot solve.

In `java`, if i wanted to search for a label with a Wrapper, i can do it in that way:

```
Wrap<? extends Label> label = Root.ROOT.lookup().wrap().as(Parent.class, Node.class).lookup(Label.class).wrap();
```

If i want to do that in Scala, i get no working solution. I have tried it already in that way:

```
val label: Wrap[_<:Label] = Root.ROOT.lookup().wrap().as(classOf[Parent[_<:Label]], classOf[Node]).lookup(classOf[Label]).wrap()
```

But then scala tells me: - inferred type arguments `[javafx.scene.Node,org.jemmy.interfaces.Parent[_ <: javafx.scene.control.Label]]` do not conform to method as's type parameter bounds

```
 [TYPE,INTERFACE <: org.jemmy.interfaces.TypeControlInterface[TYPE]]
```

The method "as":

```
public <TYPE, INTERFACE extends TypeControlInterface<TYPE>> INTERFACE as(Class<INTERFACE> interfaceClass, Class<TYPE> type)
```

The method "lookup":

```
public abstract <ST extends T> Lookup<ST> lookup(Class<ST> paramClass);
```

The Class "Parent":

```
public abstract interface Parent<T> extends TypeControlInterface<T>
```

So i don't get it, how i can use these interfaces in scala. Is there any solution, or are there limitations of the use between scala and java?

Comment: Does `classOf[Parent[Node]]` (instead of `classOf[Parent[_ <: Label]]`) not work? If I understand correctly, `Label` is subclass of `Node`, so it should work with `lookup()` normally.

Comment: if i do it with your suggestion: val label = Root.ROOT.lookup().wrap().as(classOf[Parent[Node]]).lookup().wrap() there is an exception: " org.jemmy.interfaces.InterfaceException: org.jemmy.interfaces.Parent is not implemented for javafx.scene.Scene by org.jemmy.fx.SceneWrap (Object: javafx.scene.Scene@63a80928)"

Comment: I don't know JemmyFX framework and what it does, but in code in your comment you have omitted second argument in `.as()` method call (namely `classOf[Node]`). Maybe it is important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know nothing about JemmyFX, but here's my 2 cents.
It's not an interoperability issue between Scala and Java. It's an issue of correctly typing your call to the `as` method.

The `as` method signature says `[TYPE, INTERFACE <: TypeControlInterface[TYPE]]` which means that the INTERFACE type must be parametrized exactly with the same type than TYPE. Because of this, you cannot use `classOf[Parent[Label]]` in the first argument and `classOf[Node]` in the second argument: you must use either `Node` or `Label` twice.

I've tried to reproduce the issue with the following Scala code:

```
trait TypeControlInterface[T]
trait Parent[T] extends TypeControlInterface[T]

trait Node
case class Label(s: String) extends Node

object Test {
  def as[TYPE, INTERFACE <: TypeControlInterface[TYPE]](interfaceClass: Class[INTERFACE], typeClass: Class[TYPE]): INTERFACE = ???

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val label1 = as(classOf[Parent[Label]], classOf[Label]) // compiles
    val label2 = as(classOf[Parent[Node]], classOf[Node]) // compiles
    val label3 = as(classOf[Parent[Label]], classOf[Node]) // doesn't compile
  }
}
```

Note that if the `as` method had been defined like this:

```
def as[TYPE, INTERFACE <: TypeControlInterface[_ <: TYPE]](...)
```

the last line in the example above would have compiled.

Comment: Yeah, i see what you mean. With your solution it works fine until the test is running and i get the exception "org.jemmy.interfaces.InterfaceException: org.jemmy.interfaces.Parent is not implemented for javafx.scene.Scene by org.jemmy.fx.SceneWrap (Object: javafx.scene.Scene@63a80928)". Don't know why this works in Java but not in Scala, but i found another solution to avoid this exception. But your suggestion helps me a lot to understand my fault.